# Roman page number in multilingual abstract page

Tags: page-numbering, roman-numerals

I made my abstract page and used two languages in it.

I would like to typeset the page number in roman but it doesn't work.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,arabic]{babel}
\usepackage[LAE,LFE]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman} \setcounter{page}{3}
\selectlanguage{english}
\chapter*{ABSTRACT}

\selectlanguage{arabic}
\begin{flushleft}
\textbf{{\Large : ملخص}}
\end{flushleft}الهدف من هذا المشروع هو تصميم وتنفيذ نظام لإدارة المجلس التأديبي على شبكة الإنترنت، لقسم الإعلام الآلي في جامعة عباس لغرور، برمجة هذا النظام تمت من خلال دراسة تفصيلية عن طريق استعمال يو أم أل  والتنفيذ تم باستعمال لغة البرمجة
 بي إتش بي ونظام إدارة قاعدة البيانات  ماي إس كيو إل، للمساعدة في إدارة المهام المتعلقة بمجلس التأديب مثل : حفظ التاريخ التأديبي للطالب، إدارة الوثائق التربوية (تقرير سوء السلوك، القرار النهائي ...) ضمان التواصل بين أعضاء مجلس الإدارة ورئيس القسم (استخدام الاستدعاء)، والتخفيف من العلاجات في المجلس الذي كان يستغرق وقتا طويلا لأسباب مثل: المعالجة اليدوية للمعلومات، وجود عدد كبير من السجلات وعدم وجود شكل موحد للتقارير والاستدعاء.
\selectlanguage{english}
\begin{flushleft}
\textbf{{\Large Abstract:}}
\end{flushleft}\selectlanguage{english}
The aim of this project  is to design and implement a web based disciplinary board management system, for the department of informatics in the university of Abbas Laghrour ,for modelling the system we used UML language and for the implementation we used  PHP language and MyQSL data base ,to help with the management of task related to disciplinary board such as : saving the disciplinary history of the student ,managing the pedagogical documents(report of misconduct, final decision …) ensuring communication between board members and department chief (using convocation) ,and to alleviate the treatments of the  board which used to take too much time  for reasons such as : the manual processing of information ,the big number of registers and the lack of a standard format for reports and convocation.
\begin{flushleft}
\textbf{{\Large Résumé:}}
\end{flushleft}
Le but de ce projet est de concevoir et mettre en place un système de gestion de conseil disciplinaire basé sur le Web, pour le département de l'informatique de l'université d'Abbas Laghrour,Pour la modélisation du système on a utilisé le langage UML et pur l'implimentation on a utilisé le langage PHP et la base de données MyQSL, pour aider à la gestion des tâches liées au conseil de discipline en tant que: sauvegarder les antécédents disciplinaires de les etudiants, gérer les documents pédagogiques (rapport d'inconduite, décision finale ...) assurer la communication entre les membres du conseil d'administration et le chef du département (en utilisant la convocation) et pour atténuer les traitements du conseil qui prenait trop Temps pour des raisons telles que: le traitement manuel de l'information, le grand nombre de registres et le manque de format standard pour les rapports et la convocation.
\newpage

\end{document}
```

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/251886/103046